# Selenium, exception on getting a file in IE using WebClient

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, setcookie, webclient

I have a Selenium test that should download a file and check if it contains something. The test run ok in Firefox and Chrome but in **IE 11** I get an exception.

**IE driver**: IEDriverServer version 2.41.0.0

The code :

```
<code>
 var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
 //....navigate and login to a page
 var el = driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText("Download File"))
                                             .First(p => p.GetAttribute("href").Contains("/downloadmyfile"));
 var link = el.GetAttribute("href");
 var client = new WebClient();
 client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = CookieString();
 var data = client.DownloadString(new Uri(link));
</code>
```

The code to copy the cookies:

```
<code>
  public string CookieString()
    {
        var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;
        return string.Join("; ", cookies.Select(c => string.Format("{0}={1}", c.Name, c.Value)));
    }
</code>
```

The exception :

- Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
- InnerException:  Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies for Firefox driver looks:

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=sesionId222222; .authcookie=xxxxxxxx; __utma=1.559549671.1404381398.1404381398.1404381398.1; __utmb=1.1.10.1404381398; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1404381398.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); testingSite=culture=en
```

The driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies for IE driver looks:

```
__utma=1.342629986.1404310901.1404378456.1404381205.3; __utmb=1.2.10.1404381205; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1404310901.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); testingSite=culture=en
```

For the same web page the browser cookie for IE browser has sessionId and .authcookie.

Anyone has a **clue** on what can go wrong with IE driver?

I see that the IE driver doesn't contain the cookies value for _SessionId and .authcookie
**There is a way to get the missing cookies for IE driver?**

- InnerException StackTrace :

  > at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  >    at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
  >     at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
  >   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  >     at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
  >   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  >     at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, 
  >   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  >     at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  >     at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  >     at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, 
  >   Boolean probeRead)

  - Exception StackTrace :

> ```
> -at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
>  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
>  at MyClasss........
> ```

Comment: I see that the problem is with the IE driver, it can't get the cookies.

Comment: Stack trace please. What version of IE and what version of the IEDriver? Do the cookies look the same in IE when going to the site manually?

Comment: I have installed the latest version of IE 11. The IE driver for selenium is IEDriverServer.exe version 2.41.0.0. The cookie in fiddler has sessionId and authCookie.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that IE does not return HttpOnly cookies. The ASP.NET SessionID is an HttpOnly cookie.

We found no solution, so we switched to performing the download using a JavaScript-AJAX request that we inject into the page. We also return the result as an encoded string back to Selenium, so we do not spam the HDD with downloaded files.